# Access 2013: Send the form's current record only to a PDF using a report

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form where users input all of their data. There is a 'Save' button which saves the record, and leaves the form up and active.
Before I close the form, I need to take that newly saved record and output the associated report to a PDF file.
My problem right now is that the output to the PFD is sending all records in the table, not just the record in the form.
Here is my code at this point.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim outl As Outlook.Application
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strWhere As String

    Cause = "SaveButton"
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    'Save the Record
    Me.btnClose.SetFocus

    If Me.DateOfVisit <> "" Then
        Me.RepStatus = "Report Saved!"
        Me.btnNewReport.Visible = True

    'Now, print the report to a PDF File
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptReports", acFormatPDF,"C:\ReportTest.pdf", False

    End If

End Sub
```

As a side note, it is required that the users would not see a report pop up on the screen and then quickly disappear.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I finally noodled it out.
I added the following lines and now it is working.
Turns out that the OutputTo has no way to pass in any search criteria.
So, I opened the report in Hidden mode so the users don't see anything and then use the OutputTo to send it to a PDF.

```
'Now, print the report to a PDF File

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptReports", acViewReport, , "[ReportID] = " & [ReportID], acHidden
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptReports", acFormatPDF, "C:\TG QUOTE SYSTEM\Meeting Reports\ReportTest.pdf", False
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptReports"
```

End If

Thanks all.